# Laravel what does a class name stands for after function parameterlist

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I saw this in a code, but I can't figure it out, and I didn't find it in documentation (Most probably I don't know how to search)

so it's like that in a model:

```
public function functionName(int $parameter): ClassName{...}
```

What does the Class after the parameter list stands for?

Comment: its called return type declarations. Return type declaration is specifying the expected data types of the result that a function or a class method should return. refer here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_returntype_declarations.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function functionName(int $parameter): ClassName{...}
```

In this case `ClassName` is written to specify the return type of function.

`functionName` returns object instance of `ClassName`

you can read more about return types here: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types

Comment: I'm glad to help you. please close question by accepting this answer if you find it helpful

Comment: Yes I will, just need to wait until s/o lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

this is the return type declarations. PHP7 introduces this syntex.
It indicates the types of value that the function will return.

you can use `int` `float` and it's not limited to array you can use your own class

```
public function functionName(int $parameter): ClassName{...}
```

it's not just readability, if the function returns anything elase then it will throw an error